# onClick add Class to a maximum of 3 elements and disabling click for remaining elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select 3 elements from 6 in the features section. After a max of 3 is selected, I would like onClick addClass to stop working for the remaining elements.

Once I have this functionality in the features section, I'd like to connect it with the 'How much would you like to spend' section. Once one element is selected here and 3 are selected from there, I'd like for the footer display to be set from none to on. And for it then to go to none if any element is deselected.

I've added Jquery for elements to be selected, but not to be capt at 3

```js
$(document).on('click', '#price ul li', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#price ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');    
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#spec ul li', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');    
    }

});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "samsungOne";
  src: url(fonts/SamsungOne-400.woff2);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400; }
@font-face {
  font-family: "samsungOne-700";
  src: url(fonts/SamsungOne-700.woff2);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700; }
@font-face {
  font-family: "samsungSharp";
  src: url(fonts/SamsungSharpSansBd.woff);
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700; }
* {
  margin: 0; }
  * body {
    background-color: #fafafa; }
    * body h2, * body h3, * body p {
      margin: 0; }

header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d4d4d4;
  padding: 50px 0 40px 0; }
  header .content-container h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "samsungSharp", Arial; }
  header .content-container p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "SamsungOne", Arial; }

main {
  padding: 45px 20px 30px 20px; }
  main .content-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto; }
    main .content-container h3 {
      margin: 0 0 18px;
      font-family: "SamsungOne-700", Arial; }
    main .content-container .content-row {
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 45px; }
      main .content-container .content-row ul {
        padding: 0px; }
        main .content-container .content-row ul li {
          list-style: none;
          display: inline; }
          main .content-container .content-row ul li button {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 1px 4px 1px #e5e5e5;
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 1% 15px 1%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 25px 0px; }
            main .content-container .content-row ul li button img {
              height: 50px; }
            main .content-container .content-row ul li button h3 {
              margin-bottom: 6px;
              font-family: "SamsungOne-700", Arial; }
            main .content-container .content-row ul li button p {
              font-family: "SamsungOne", Arial; }
          main .content-container .content-row ul li button:hover {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000; }
          main .content-container .content-row ul li button:focus {
            outline: none; }
        main .content-container .content-row ul li.active button {
          border: 3px solid #142c98; }
        main .content-container .content-row ul li.active button:hover {
          box-shadow: none; }

#price button img {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 6px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  #price button {
    width: 29.2%; }
    #price button img {
      height: 15px; }
    #price button p {
      font-size: 13px; } }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #spec button {
    width: 47%; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  #spec button {
    width: 100%; } }

footer {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000000; }
  footer .content-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px 0; }
    footer .content-container p {
      text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 0px;
      font-family: "SamsungOne", Arial; }
      footer .content-container p img {
        position: relative;
        top: 8px;
        width: 28px; }
      footer .content-container p button {
        background-color: #162992;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 15px 40px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 25px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Samsung</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-container">
            <h2>Find your ideal Galaxy A Series phone</h2>
            <p>Select you preferences below and we'll recommend the right phone for you.</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="price" class="content-container">
            <h3>How much would you like to spend?</h3>
            <div class="content-row">
                <ul> 
                    <li class="">   
                        <button type="button" >
                            <img src="assets/£.svg" height="30px" alt="Pound sign" />
                            <p>Upto £219</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/££.svg" height="30px" alt="Two pound signs" />
                            <p>£309-£359</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/£££.svg" height="30px" alt="Three pound signs" />
                            <p>£489+</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="spec" class="content-container">
            <h3>Pick the 3 features most important to you</h3>
            <div class="content-row">
                <ul>
                    <li class="">
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Screen.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Screen size</h3>
                            <p>Ejoying films, games and photos</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Camera.png" width="50px" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Camera</h3>
                            <p>Taking amazing photos and selfies</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Storage.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Storage</h3>
                            <p>Space for music, movies and games</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Battery.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Battery life</h3>
                            <p>Power to keep up with busy lives</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">   
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Performace.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Perfomance</h3>
                            <p>Run multiple apps at once with ease</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Gaming.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Gaming</h3>
                            <p>Playing graphics intensive games</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>    
                </ul>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-container">
            <p>
                <img src="assets/thick.png" alt="tick" />
                <span>It's a match!</span> We've found a great Galaxy A phone for you
                <button>View phone</button>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your code, without it we can't tell you what you did wrong, or make an example that fits your code.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question to include your code. Note for future reference that we only require the relevant code, not all of it in its entirety. I've added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need to count the number of `li` elements which have the `.active` class. If it's at the limit then don't add it to the clicked element. You also need to check if the current element has the class and allow it to be removed.

Also note that the class adding/removing logic can be simplified by using `toggleClass()`. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#spec ul li', function() {
  var selectedCount = $(this).siblings().filter('.active').length;
  if (selectedCount < 3 || $(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  } else {
    // display a warning to the user here...
    console.log('only 3 can be selected');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

* body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

main {
  padding: 45px 20px 30px 20px;
}

main .content-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

main .content-container h3 {
  margin: 0 0 18px;
  font-family: "SamsungOne-700", Arial;
}

main .content-container .content-row {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 1px #e5e5e5;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1% 15px 1%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0px;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li button img {
  height: 50px;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li button h3 {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-family: "SamsungOne-700", Arial;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li button p {
  font-family: "SamsungOne", Arial;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li button:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li.active button {
  border: 3px solid #142c98;
}

main .content-container .content-row ul li.active button:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #spec button {
    width: 47%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  #spec button {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="spec" class="content-container">
    <h3>Pick the 3 features most important to you</h3>
    <div class="content-row">
      <ul>
        <li class="">
          <button>
            <img src="assets/Screen.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
            <h3>Screen size</h3>
            <p>Ejoying films, games and photos</p>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <button>
            <img src="assets/Camera.png" width="50px" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
            <h3>Camera</h3>
            <p>Taking amazing photos and selfies</p>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <button>
            <img src="assets/Storage.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
            <h3>Storage</h3>
            <p>Space for music, movies and games</p>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <button>
            <img src="assets/Battery.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
            <h3>Battery life</h3>
            <p>Power to keep up with busy lives</p>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <button>
            <img src="assets/Performace.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
            <h3>Perfomance</h3>
            <p>Run multiple apps at once with ease</p>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <button>
            <img src="assets/Gaming.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
            <h3>Gaming</h3>
            <p>Playing graphics intensive games</p>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan, can you help me with displaying the footer after both section's elements have been selected? I've added `if ($('#price ul li.active').length > 0 && $('#spec ul li.active').length > 1) {
    $("footer").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $("footer").css("display", "none");
  }` but it doesn't want to work.

Comment: Hard to debug without a full example, but that seems ok, so long as you run it in the `click` handler above.